# Unknown authentication strategy "local"

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate users on my website and I got this error

> Unknown authentication strategy 'local-login'

I've tried changing the name of the strategy, also I've read other threads in SO but didn't find a solution.

```
// Passport
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ' + connection.escape(id), function(err, rows) {
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password'
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ' + connection.escape(username), function(err, rows) {
        if(err)
            return done(err);
        if(!rows.length) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Invalid username or password. Please try again.'));
        }
        if(!(rows[0].password == password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Invalid username or password. Please try again.'));

        return done(null, rows[0]);
    });
  }));
}

// Express Router
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use('/static', express.static('./static'));

app.post('/login/auth', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check your installation with:

```
npm install passport passport-local --save
```

Then import passport like below:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

before your `app.use()` methods:

```
...
..
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Then use it as follows. (No need to give 'local-login' as a first argument)

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password'
}, (req, username, password, done) => {
     // Your logic here...
       ...
       .. 
  }));
}
```

Finally in your router:

```
app.post('/login/auth', passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/dashboard', 
    failureRedirect: '/', 
    failureFlash: true }),
 function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
 });
```

More info:
[passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local)

Comment: What should I include in config/passport? I don't have that file

Comment: it was like this before **const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;** and it didn't work

Comment: @GhoSTBG What is the error are you getting? Check your installations with 'npm list' command in your directory.

Comment: I think i fixed it by leaving empty space like this passport.authenticate(' ', { successRedirect: '/dashboard' });